# Magento 2 custom module jQuery loading issue

Tags: jquery, magento2.3.4

My custom module:

app\code\Zero\my_module\view\frontend\web\js\changezipcode.js

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $('#form').hide();
                 $("#changeButton").click(function() {
                     $("#form").toggle('slow');
                 });

                 $("#submit").click(function() {
                    var zipcode= $("#zipcode").val();
                    alert("Value: " + zipcode);
                });
        });
});
```

app\code\Zero\my_module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            changezipcode:   'Zero_my_module/js/changezipcode',
        },
    }
};
```

Onclick event not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

In your `requirejs-config.js` file add dependency of `jQuery` like this

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'changezipcode': 'Zero_my_module/js/changezipcode'
},
 shim: {
    'changezipcode': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
}
};
```

After this, when you will call `changezipcode` it will be dependent on jquery

Comment: Still getting issue : https://snipboard.io/iuMODe.jpg

Comment: changezipcode.js   - https://justpaste.it/38q9t and 
requirejs-config.js  - https://justpaste.it/6eewa

Answer (score 0):

```
 require([
           "jquery",
           'Zero_my_module/js/changezipcode'
       ], function ($, firebase) {
           'use strict';
       $(document).ready(function() 
       {
           $('#form').hide();
                $("#changeButton").click(function() {
                    $("#form").toggle('slow');
                });

                $("#submit").click(function() {
                   var zipcode= $("#zipcode").val();
                   alert("Value: " + zipcode);
               });
       });
```

Comment: implement this code

Comment: it's not working, https://codeshare.io/Gbxen7 any help thanks.

Comment: requirejs-config.js - justpaste.it/6eewa and Still getting issue : https://snipboard.io/iuMODe.jpg